# Get value and key lists out of pandas groupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to create three arrays that I need for some stats.
I need all the fields, the month and the number of finishes and starts in that month.

My dataframe is the following

```
           month  finish  started
0  MONTH.Mar       1        0
1  MONTH.Mar       1        0
2  MONTH.Mar       1        0
3  MONTH.Mar       1        0
4  MONTH.Mar       1        0
5  MONTH.Mar       0        1
6  MONTH.Apr       1        0
7  MONTH.Mar       0        1
8  MONTH.Mar       0        1
9  MONTH.Feb       0        1
```

I do a groupby:

```
df.groupby('month').sum()
```

and the output is the following:

```
           finish  started
month                     
MONTH.Apr       1        0
MONTH.Feb       0        1
MONTH.Mar       5        3
```

How can I convert the data into three different lists like this:

```
['MONTH.Apr','MONTH.Feb','MONTH.Mar']
[1,0,5]
[0,1,3]
```

I tried to do `frame.values.tolist()` but the output was the following:

```
[[1, 0], [0, 1], [5, 3]]
```

and it was impossible to get the months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try `reset_index()` and transposing `.T`:

```
>>> df.groupby('month').sum().reset_index().T.to_numpy()
array([['MONTH.Apr', 'MONTH.Feb', 'MONTH.Mar'],
       [1, 0, 5],
       [0, 1, 3]], dtype=object)
```

Or:

```
>>> df.groupby('month').sum().reset_index().T.values.tolist()
[['MONTH.Apr', 'MONTH.Feb', 'MONTH.Mar'], [1, 0, 5], [0, 1, 3]]
```

Comment: Prefer to use `as_index=False` as parameter of `groupby` rather than `reset_index`. IMHO :)

Comment: I use the first one cause it's the simplest one, however don't understand what is transposing .T, but it works perfectly. Can you also explain reset_index if possible? Thank you very much.

Comment: [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html): Convert rows to columns. [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html): Convert the index to a column

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
month, finish, started = df.groupby('month', as_index=False) \
                           .sum().to_dict('list').values()
```

Output:

```
>>> month
['MONTH.Apr', 'MONTH.Feb', 'MONTH.Mar']

>>> finish
[1, 0, 5]

>>> started
[0, 1, 3]
```